# Doubt about Windows 10 in UEFI mode and Ubuntu in Legacy mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, grub-legacy

I've got a doubt about uefi/legacy mode. I'm looking for an advice because I'm not really sure about what can happens.
My problem is the following:

my laptop have already installed Windows 10 in UEFI (and previously I had in legacy mode the ubuntu partition that for some reasons I had to remove and give all the space back to Windows). Now I need to reinstall the ubuntu partiton and for doing this I can only use the legacy mode(due to problems with acer laptop).

All right then, I have my pendrive with ubuntu ISO and if I try to install it i get this message
[image]

***So my question is:*** if I click on 'install now' I will lose everything in my disk or not? What problems might I face? Obiviously I'm afraid of losing the all windows partition.

Comment: Do not mix modes. Down that path is a long afternoon of tears and lost data. Install both using UEFI.

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend to not use Ubuntu 14.04 (looked at your tags), whose support is expired and its support for UEFI maaayyy be worse than a modern Ubuntu like 18.04 or 19.04.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? And confirmed drive is in AHCI mode, not RAID nor Intel SRT?  (add AHCI drive in Windows first). This is similar for all Acer models. What model is yours? Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: thanks a lot, I fixed it using the 'something else' option and installing my ubuntu distro in legacy w\out losing anything.